MIdnight Commander for Windows - switch language to English
Windows 10 LTSC Russian
MC last version
MC is in Russian by default. Does anybody have an idea how to switch it to English?

set LANG=en_US.utf8 && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander\mc.exe"

You can delete or rename the locale folder from
C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander

Without the language files the program will fall back to the default English.
